# R Markdown Error reading bibliography: pandoc document conversion failed with error 25

Tags: r, r-markdown, mendeley

pandoc seems to have a problem with reading my bib file giving me this error:

```
Error reading bibliography file library.bib:
(line 19001, column 1):
unexpected "@"
expecting space, ",", white space or "}"
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 25
Execution halted
```

I am using Mendeley to produce my library.bib and the file includes all of my references (almost 30 thousand lines).
When I search the line in question, everything seems to be in order (no unusual characters). Deleting the reference doesn't help. The "@" from the error is at the beginning of every reference in the file.
Using a smaller subset of my reference list from another folder doesn't help, I only managed to knit my document with a very small subset (1000 lines).
The library.bib is a copy in my project folder so it is not influenced by running Mendeley.

I can make a subfolder with references needed for this only document but it doesn't provide a long-term solution - I would like to use the whole library and not make a subfolder for each document I am working on.

Is there something simple I am missing?
Thanks!

Comment: This error infers that you have a reference starting before the previous one ended. You may be missing the closing bracket of that line or the preceding line. Instead of `@ref{whatever}@ref{whatever}`, you may have `@ref{whatever@ref{whatever}`. If this is the problem, that would also account for why you have issues even with a smaller subset. When you reduced the count, you still have an uneven amount of opening and closing brackets.

Comment: thank you! I made a new ref library which again gave me the same error but there was a } missing at the end of the abstract which I  missed