# Rmarkdown bibliography conversion error 25

Tags: pdf, reference, r-markdown, knitr, citations

I am trying to knit my Rmarkdown file in a pdf document and I am hitting a conversion error 25 when it comes to a citation. Here is a simpler version of the document, I left all the packages from the original document in case the error was linked to the YAM section:

```
---
title: "Title here" 
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d-%B-%Y')`"
author: 
  - Pierre-Alexandre Dumas
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes        
    includes:  
      in_header: my_header.tex
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: false
  bookdown::pdf_document2: default
bibliography: library.bib   
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage[french]{babel}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
- \renewcommand{\and}{\\}
- \usepackage{titling}
- \usepackage{tocloft}
- \renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
---
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage
# Introduction
Bla bla bla (<1%; [@Eadie2020]).
```

Here is the .bib entry as it is in library.bib. The .bib document is in the same folder as the R project. Note that it is the only entry in the list for the moment.

```
@book_section{Eadie2020,
   author = {John M. Eadie and Jean-Pierre L. Savard and Mark L. Mallory},
   city = {Ithaca},
   doi = {10.2173/bow.bargol.01},
   editor = {Alan F. Poole and Frank B. Gill},
   journal = {Birds of the World},
   month = {3},
   publisher = {Cornell Lab of Ornithology},
   title = {Barrow's Goldeneye (Bucephala islandica)},
   year = {2020},
}
```

And here is the error in R:

```
Error reading bibliography file library.bib:
(line 1, column 6):
unexpected '_'
Erreur : pandoc document conversion failed with error 25
Exécution arrêtée
```

I modified the .bib document name, to no avail. I also tried playing with the {} and [] as mentionned here [R Markdown Error reading bibliography: pandoc document conversion failed with error 25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70799015/r-markdown-error-reading-bibliography-pandoc-document-conversion-failed-with-er) but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED.

I realized that mendeley insert a "_" between book and section, which apparently is not supported by r-markdown.